# Multi Domain Mocking with WireMock is not working

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm trying to use WireMock to mock 2 different external APIs, each of which is in a different domain, but It's not working. I tried to follow [this doc](https://wiremock.org/docs/multi-domain-mocking/), like this:

```
package me.brunosantana.wiremock.integration;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.JvmProxyConfigurer;
import jakarta.annotation.Resource;
import me.brunosantana.wiremock.util.FileReaderUtil;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.options;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

//https://wiremock.org/docs/multi-domain-mocking/

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("profile1")
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Resource
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    WireMockServer wireMockServer;

    @BeforeEach
    public void startServer() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        FileReaderUtil fileReaderUtil = new FileReaderUtil();
        String body1 = fileReaderUtil.read("jsonplaceholder-response.json");
        String body2 = fileReaderUtil.read("bible-response.json");

        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options()
                .dynamicPort()
                .enableBrowserProxying(true)
                .trustAllProxyTargets(true)
        );
        wireMockServer.start();

        JvmProxyConfigurer.configureFor(wireMockServer);

        wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/albums/[0-9]+/photos"))
                .withHost(WireMock.equalTo("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                        .withBody(body1)));

        wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/[a-z]+\\s[0-9]+:[0-9]+"))
                .withHost(WireMock.equalTo("my.random.site.com"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                        .withBody(body2)));
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void stopServer() {
        wireMockServer.stop();
        JvmProxyConfigurer.restorePrevious();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAlbumBibleEndpointUsingRestAssured() {
        given()
        .when()
            .get("http://localhost:8080/albums/1/bible/john/3/16")
        .then()
            .log().all()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("album.albumId", is(1))
            .body("album.photos[0].title", equalTo("accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt mock"))
            .body("bible.reference", equalTo("John 3:16 mock"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAlbumBibleEndpointUsingMockMvc() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("http://localhost:8080/albums/1/bible/john/3/16")
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        .headers(new HttpHeaders()))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is2xxSuccessful())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.album.photos[0].title").value("accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt mock"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.bible.reference").value("John 3:16 mock"))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andReturn();
    }

}
```

But when I run this code I get this error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Server Error: "Network failure trying to make a proxied request from WireMock to http://my.random.site.com/john%203:16<EOL><EOL>my.random.site.com"
```

The same error is shown, both using Rest Assured and MockMvc to execute the test (both methods in the test class above). It's like the WireMock is trying to reach the wrong URL (the my.random.site.com part appears duplicated in the URL). Why is that?

Just clarifying a little bit, in the tests I call the controller, which in turn calls the services that call the external APIs.

If you want to execute the code, it's [here](https://github.com/brunosantanati/integration-tests/blob/main/wiremock/src/test/java/me/brunosantana/wiremock/integration/IntegrationTest.java) in GitHub.

I kind of get a way around it, using 2 WireMock Servers, but since it's not the solution the documentation recommends for multiple domains, I'm not sure if I should use it (you can see it [here](https://github.com/brunosantanati/integration-tests/blob/main/wiremock/src/test/java/me/brunosantana/wiremock/integration/AnotherIntegrationTest.java)). Anyway, it should work the way as the documentation says it should.

Thank you!